# Lenovo IdeaPad: Original keyboard dead keys, replacement randomly made keystokes then failed

Tags: keyboard, replace, laptop, touchpad

Problem is too complex to fit in Subject line.

First, my keyboard had some dead keys, so I replaced it with a new keyboard . The replacement keyboard started to make <kbd>Enter</kbd> keystrokes randomly by itself. I restarted the Lenovo Ideapad, and now the internal keyboard doesn't work. Also, Kubuntu doesn't recognize the internal touchpad. I must use an external USB keyboard and 
 mouse.

Note: After the Power On Self Test, an error code, white on black, flashes onto the screen for only one second so I can't save it.

I think the replacement keyboard is not faulty, since all buttons work, but the random keystrokes problem occurs in Windows 10. Those random keystrokes keep me from selecting anything but Windows.

```
ahmet@ahmet:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ LITE-ON Technology USB NetVista Full Width Keyboard.      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
ahmet@ahmet:~$
```

FOLLOW THROUGH POST:

the error starts with:
**system bootorxer not found initial**

Suddenly the internal keyboard behaved, no random <kbd>Enter</kbd> keystrokes; then it returned, and the touchpad doesn't work, so it's back to the external USB keyboard and mouse.

Comment: the enter key presses automatically in linux and in windows? ... if that is true, then you have a hardware problem .... why are you posting here?

Comment: Yes, you have a hardware problem. You can disable events from the internal keyboard and/or touchpad, so the "automatic enter" doesn't get in the way. There was at least one question for that either here or on superuser.